# Save date to MySQL format by using Laravel Carbon

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, date, php-carbon

Trying to convert JQuery Datepicker date format 'dd-mm-yy' to MySQL date format 'YYYY-MM-DD' before saving to database using Carbon.

I have tried using Carbon in store method before inserting data but still no luck, it saves date as '0000-00-00'.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="reg_date" id="regdate" value="{{ old('reg_date', date('d/m/Y')) }}">
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#regdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown'
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'reg_date' => 'required',
            'first_name' => 'required|alpha',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha',
        ]);

        $object = new ModelName();
        $regdate = 'reg_date';
        $object->date = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $regdate)->format('Y-m-d');

        ModelName::create($data); // create() method to insert data to database.
    }
```

Date should save in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format to database.

```
PS: Data type is 'DATE'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using today's date as an example, the JQuery Datepicker format of `dd-mm-yy` sounds to me like it would display as `10-08-19`.

But in your Carbon declaration, you are using `d-m-Y`, which expects a 4 digit year `10-08-2019`.

Trying changing your input format to `d-m-y` to account for the 2 digit year.

```php
$object->date = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $regdate)->format('Y-m-d');
```

More information on PHP date formatting:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**Edit:** Other issues, plus changes made per comments.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'reg_date' => 'required',
    ]);

    // get the entire request as an array
    $data = $request->all();

    // correct the date format
    $data['reg_date'] = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $data['reg_date'])->format('Y-m-d');

    // create a new model
    $model = ModelName::create($data);
}
```

**Edit 2:** Process multiple dates by keys.

```php
$keys = ['reg_date','sell_date','purchase_date'];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $data[$key] = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $data[$key])->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: No! the date format displaying as a 10-08-2019 because I am using 'old' helper in that field {{ old('reg_date', date('d/m/Y')) }} to retrieve data after validation fails.

Comment: Even if you ignore the date format, all of that other stuff mentioned is still a mess.  And `d/m/Y` isn't even in the ballpark of the other date formats mentioned...  What do you get if you `dd(request('reg_date'));` after the validation?

Comment: But it inserts only one reg_date value to database "2019-08-10", I have several other fields too, can you please tell me how to do this using create() method, please check I have edited my question.

Comment: Perfect! for me it's working with 'd-m-Y' in carbon also what if I have more than one columns to convert? reg_date, purchase_date, sell_date etc?

Comment: Same as above, just create another line and change the array keys as appropriate: `$data['your_date_field'] = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $data['your_date_field'])->format('Y-m-d');`.  The key is referenced twice per line.

Comment: Can I use like this? $data['reg_date','purchase_date'] = \Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['reg_date','purchase_date'])->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: No, but you could loop through a set of keys.  See additional edits.